# React import CSS file of react-image-gallery library in a CSS module file

Tags: reactjs, import, react-css-modules

since i want a unique CSS file for a specific component i decided to use CSS module file
but i noticed the import of CSS file of a library that im using called **react-image-gallery** doesn't work anymore

```
@import "~react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
```

knowing that it worked on normal CSS file but not on **css.module** file
how can i fix it?